# Passing a macro 2 dimensional array to a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I am trying a pass a 2 dimensional array (actual size is 20000 x 50) from a macro to Google Sheet. I found code to do this but I get an exception error:
Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues. 
on the range.setValues(data1) line.

```
function Analyze() {

  var data1 = [10, 2]; // Defining a 10x2 array  

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  data1[1, 1] = "Linda";
  data1[1, 2] = "Blue";

  data1[2, 1] = "Tom";
  data1[2, 2] = "Orange";

  var range = spreadsheet.getRange(1, 1, data1.length, 2);

  range.setValues(data1);

}
```

Can anyone figure out issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
var data1 = [ 10 , 2 ]; // Defining a one dimensional array with 2 values
```

You need to create a two dimensional array... In JavaScript it is basically an array nested in an array.

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var data1 = [];

data1[0] = ["Linda","Blue"];
data1[1] = ["Tom","Orange"];

var range = spreadsheet.getRange(1, 1, 2, 2);
range.setValues(data1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you were trying to do:

```
function Analyze() {
  var data1=[['',''],['',''],['',''],['',''],['',''],['',''],['',''],['',''],['',''],['','']];
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  data1.forEach(function(r,i){r[0]='Name'+i+'0';r[1]='Name'+i+'1'})
  Logger.log(data1);
  sh.getRange(1,1,10,2).setValues(data1);  
}
```

You can also  do it this way:

```
function Analyze() {
  var data1= [...Array(10)].map(e => Array(2));
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  data1.forEach(function(r,i){r[0]='Name'+i+'0';r[1]='Name'+i+'1'})
  Logger.log(data1);
  sh.getRange(1,1,10,2).setValues(data1);  
}
```

Image:

[image]